# Filter out trailing slash type URL with regex

Tags: regex

I want to capture `www.example.com/stuff/morestuff` from the following list:

```
www.example.com/stuff/morestuff
www.example.com/stuff/morestuff/
www.example.com/stuff/morestuff///
```

I was trying this regex:

`^(.*)(?:\/)*$`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing a `?` after a `*`, makes it non-greedy, i.e. it stops consuming characters as early as possible. In this case:

```
^(.*?)(?:\/)*$
```

it will consume only up till the first slash.

Depending on the regex implementation you may not have to escape the forward slash.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex instead:

```
^(?:https?:\/\/)?(.*?)\/*$
```

and use captured group #1 for your case.

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/V8CYQS/2)

Comment: Thanks for improving my https vs http part as well, as seen in my demo.